# Jquery - Limit text in text input, not textarea

Tags: jquery, ipad, ios5

Using jquery how can I limit the number of characters that can be typed in a text field? Not referring to a textarea, just a normal text input field. I have a form and viewing via an iPad using IOS5 the maxlength attribute for some reason is ignored. If I used maxlength=10 I can type forever in this field, it wont stop at 10 characters. So it looks like I will need jquery to limit the field. Any suggestions?

**Update**

Using the example from maxedison and the suggestion from Marc B this is the code I came up with that worked:

```
$('#textfld','#textform').keyup(function() {

    if($(this).val().length > 20) {

        var text = $(this).val().substring(0,20);
        $(this).val(text);

    }

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to bind to the keydown event for the field and prevent it from entering a character if there are already 10 in that field: http://jsfiddle.net/j6tJ3/

```
    $('input').keydown(function(e){
        if($(this).val().length > 9 && e.which !== 8 && e.which !== 46){ //if it's too long and the key pressed isn't backspace or delete
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: This'll prevent someone from deleting a character if the string's at max length. Best is to check on keyup and replace the field's value with a 9char substring if it's over the limit.

Comment: Good point. I've modifed the IF statement to allow the backspace and delete keys. Using keyup isn't a great option because you will see the key get entered and then removed. The one situation my solution does not handle now is if someone tries copying & pasting in a longer string. That could be solved by disallowing the entry of the character if the `e` property's metaKey value is true, as well as disabling a right-click. But I think that is all going way too far, and it would be better to simply check the value prior to submitting the form, and alert the user if an issue exists.